# Click on ListView item not opening new Activity

Tags: android, listview, android-activity

I have a ListView "resultList", but clicking on an item is not opening the new (detailed) Activity. What's my mistake? 
Thank you!

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    this.resultList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.resultList) ;
    this.dataSource = MyExpenseOpenHandler.getInstance(this).readAllExpenses();
    this.adapter = new ExpenseOverviewAdapter(this, dataSource);
    this.resultList.setAdapter(adapter);
    this.resultList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, final int i, final long l) {
            Object element = adapterView.getAdapter().getItem(i);

            if (element instanceof Expense) {
                Expense expense = (Expense) element; 
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ExpenseDetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(ExpenseDetailActivity.EXPENSE_KEY, expense); 
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            Log.e("Click on List: ", element.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you place your `Log.e("Click on List: ", element.toString());` in the `if(element instanceof Expense)` block to see if it's being executed?

Comment: simply `if(element instanceof Expense) ` is `false`

Comment: @Jochen Scheele What is the type of DataSource? I think your problem is that your startActivity code simply isn't executing because element isn't an instance of Expense.

Comment: Thanks to all the comments. I will go for your recommendations and then come back with questions (if needed). Many thanks for your fast responses!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems alright .I think the problem is that your if condition may be returning false and the code inside the if statement is not being executed.You can put a log message inside the if statement to check if the code is being executed.

```
if (element instanceof Expense) {
                Log.d(YOUR_LOG_TAG,"The if condition not executed")
                Expense expense = (Expense) element; 
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ExpenseDetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(ExpenseDetailActivity.EXPENSE_KEY, expense); 
                startActivity(intent);
            }
```

If you see the log message in your android monitor you can be sure that the code inside your if condition is not executed and hence your activity is not starting.

Comment: I wrote the casting in front of the if-clause ( Expense expense = (Expense) element; ). Then it is working and opening the new window. However, I do still not understand why (Object element = adapterView.getAdapter().getItem(i);) is not the Expense instance I want it to be... Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Did you implement **Parcelable** on  your class Expense ?

Something like this

```
public class Expense implements Parcelable{
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String grade;

    // Constructor
    public Expense(String id, String name, String grade){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.grade = grade;
   }
   // Getter and setter methods
   .........
   .........

   // Parcelling part
   public Expense(Parcel in){
       String[] data = new String[3];

       in.readStringArray(data);
       // the order needs to be the same as in writeToParcel() method
       this.id = data[0];
       this.name = data[1];
       this.grade = data[2];
   }

   @Оverride
   public int describeContents(){
       return 0;
   }

   @Override
   public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
       dest.writeStringArray(new String[] {this.id,
                                           this.name,
                                           this.grade});
   }
   public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
       public Expense createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
           return new Expense(in); 
       }

       public Expense[] newArray(int size) {
           return new Expense[size];
       }
   };
```

}

Answer (score 0):

what kind of view in the list, if the child view get the focus like button may lead to item click not work well.
you can try to add `android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"` in you listview.

Comment: or add android:clickable="false" android:focuable="false" on you child view